# How to install PgAdmin4 on Ubuntu 18.04 Server mode

Tags: software-installation, pgadmin

I am using an ubuntu 18.04 server through putty on windows 10. I am trying to install PgAdmin4 on it.

I am using this tutorial for that:
[How to install PgAdmin4 on Ubuntu 18.04 Server mode](http://www.nixgyd.com/install-pgadmin4-ubuntu-18-04-server-mode/392)

When I reach the step **Configure PgAdmin4 using config_local.py** and run the command:

```
vim ~/.pgadmin4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/config_local.py
```

The terminal shows few blue dots on left side of the screen vertically, each line having one of left side corner and at the bottom right of screen it writes `1,1   All` and terminal is halted. Nothing happens.

I am not able to understand what to do. I am a novice to ubuntu.

Comment: i think this fine, at the bottom right of screen writes `1,1  ALL` mean your cursor at 1 line 1 column on all text file.

Comment: or try using another text editor and add pgadmin4 configuration you want sir

Comment: thank you very much @abu-ahmedal-khatiri: though when I try to save file, it raises error:

"~/.pgadmin4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/config_local.py" E212: Can't open file for writing

Comment: see on `vimtutor` how to write and save file using vim sir

Comment: did you try with `:w <filename>` sir?

Comment: thank you, it is written and saved. Though it raises error in the next step i.e. 'Run pgAdmin4 Python file with sudo'. When I run the command, it raises error
"python: can't open file '/root/.pgadmin4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"
Here is list of directories in pwd: 
(.pgadmin4) root@serv0138:/.pgadmin4# ls
bin  config_local.py  include  lib  local  pgadmin4-3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl  share

Comment: did your pgadmin4 configuration file saved as `config_local.py` or  `pgadmin.py` sir?

Comment: config_local.py that we crated now I would say.

Comment: you need pgadmin4.py script sir, but i don't see what the script on your link sir.

Comment: I followed all the steps in the tutorial, Do I need to follow some step again to install the script ?

Comment: see this docs https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/dev/server_deployment.html#python ,before execute pgadmin4.py you need execute setup.py sir

Comment: please can I move this thread to an chat as the system is giving me this notification ?

Comment: just click link on " Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?  "

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82819/discussion-between-xceptable-and-abu-ahmed-al-khatiri).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type

```
vim ~/.pgadmin4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/config_local.py
```

You said The terminal shows few blue dots on left side of the screen vertically, each line having one of left side corner and at the bottom right of screen it writes 1,1   All and terminal is halted.

I think this fine, at the bottom right of screen writes 1,1 ALL mean your cursor at 1 line 1 column on all text file.

When you try to save file, it raises `error: "~/.pgadmin4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/config_local.py" E212: Can't open file for writing`. for save file using VIM try with type `:w <filename>` and exit with `:quit`.

After it's written and saved. execute your python file with `sudo python config_local.py`. see below.

[image]

And then when you run pgAdmin4.py the command, it raises error `python: can't open file '/root/.pgadmin4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py': [Error 2] No such file or directory`. you get it error cause you doesn't know where pgAdmin4 data stored. check it with `locate pgadmin4` and you can found it at `/usr/local/bin/..` path. after that you can execute pgAdmin4.py see below.

[image]

If the output can showed like on your link. Congrats Sir, you can try the next steps on your link.

Hope this helps Sir.

Comment: one issue is that the terminal halted after showing msg to open pgadmin in browser window. How to return back to command prompt ?I tried cltr+D, escap key but no effect.

Comment: just use CTRL+C or CTRL+z sir.

Comment: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> worked !

Comment: sorry mistakenly written, see above sir

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82830/discussion-between-xceptable-and-abu-ahmed-al-khatiri).